# Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined when using broccoli-asset-rev

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, broccolijs

I'm using broccoli-asset-rev node module in order to avoid caching problem in ember application. After installing the module, I'm using it in my ember-cli-build.js as follows

```
var app = new EmberApp({
    fingerprint:{
        enabled:true
    }
});
```

When I use the above lines of code, I'm getting the error as

Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined.

I know this error is something related to the javascript. But if I remove the above code, everything is working properly. I don't know if I'm using the module improperly but when I followed the Github https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev everything I'm doing is same as its mentioned in the link.I've raised an issue in Github also, still no response.

If anyone had faced the similar problem or anyone who can say where I'm doing wrong, request you guys to help me.

Comment: How did you install the module? It comes included in ember-cli projects, and fingerprinting is enabled by default

Comment: Thanks @Kitler. I was not knowing that and trying add the above lines of code. Though I've not tested it, from my research it shows that the static files are updated automatically in ember cli projects